# ASP.NET - Load a LIstBox Control on Page Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I have a page with a GridView control.

Within the Gridview there is a TemplateField containing a ListBox control:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uploaded Files">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxFiles" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I need to populate this ListBox with a list of files in a folder on the server when the page loads. I am at a loss as to how to do this.

I can achieve a similar effect with a label:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uploaded Files">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxFiles" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelFiles" runat="server" Text='<%#GetFiles(Eval("DocDescription")) %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

with the following code behind

```
Public Function GetFiles(param As String)
    GetFiles = ""
    Try
        Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & Session("LastFirst") & " - " & Session("StudentUID") & "/" & param & "/")
        For Each filePath As String In filePaths
            GetFiles = GetFiles & "<br/>" & Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        Next
        GetFiles = Right(GetFiles, Len(GetFiles) - 5)
    Catch
    End Try
End Function
```

but I want the user to have the ability to select a file for deletion.

How can I populate a ListBox when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this (note: converted from C#):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each Row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim ListBoxFiles As ListBox = TryCast(Row.FindControl("ListBoxFiles"), ListBox)
            ListBoxFiles.Items.Add("aaa")
            ListBoxFiles.Items.Add("bbb")
            ListBoxFiles.Items.Add("ccc")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!